# ExecuteScript doesnt change the visibility of my element - Element not visible

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a hidden input text in my page that I need to unhide it and assing the key '*' to it. `Selenium` by default doesn't let you assign keys or access hidden elements in your page and hat's understandable, but in this case I will need access to that hidden element.
I am calling the method `ExecuteScript` from `IJavaScriptExecutor` using this code:

```
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbIsCaptchaChecked').setAttribute('display', 'flex')");
```

But still no luck as i am getting the error "Element not visible"

Here's my complete code:

```
var _driver = new ChromeDriver();
var js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbIsCaptchaChecked').setAttribute('display', 'flex')");
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbIsCaptchaChecked.hiddenRecaptcha")).SendKeys("*");
```

Comment: When you tried this `document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbIsCaptchaChecked').setAttribute('display', 'flex')` manually on browser console, does element visible??

Comment: Could it be that the time between the executeScript and the findelement is too small, the replication on the DOM has not taken place and your element is still invisible. Did you try inserting a wait in between?

Comment: @TimBourguignon I tried that , I added 10 seconds but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the style property instead:

```
"document.getElementById('...').style.display = 'flex';"
```

Note that to be considered visible by Selenium, the element also need to have a size.